# There is no menu bar on Mac OS 10.7.3

Tags: qgis, mac

I installed the latest version of QGIS on Mac OS 10.7.3 with 2 additional frameworks (GDAL Complete and GSL) but there is no main menu bar (not at the top of screen, not at the window of QGIS).

Where is the menu?

Answer (score 2):

**Context**: I believe this is a Mac issue. I had the same thing with QGIS 1.8.0 and HEAD (`d68524`) built with homebrew on OSX 10.7.5. It appeared after rebooting for the first time in a long time (initially the shutdown hung, so I did hard power off and booted up, then rebooted a second time, cleanly).

**Symptoms**: After this the menu bar at the top of the screen (the normal Mac one) was missing for QGIS. It would just show the menu of whatever application I used before I selected the QGIS window. Uninstalling and reinstalling didn't help (I tried two versions). Command-Tab application switching didn't show an icon for QGIS. Doing Exposé's "show all windows" showed the QGIS window as a thin vertical line.

**The solution** for me was:

- Delete preferences: `rm ~/Library/Preferences/org.qgis.QGIS*` (probably not necessary, but it was one of the steps I took).
- Exit all applications and shut down machine, with "Reopen windows when logging back in" unchecked.
- Boot back up, log in and start QGIS.